# PostCSS Autoprefixer not working with command line

Tags: css, postcss, autoprefixer

Right now, I'm currently working in a project in which i have to support flexbox for ie10, I'm trying to autoprefix some of my CSS code independently via terminal.

The project does not support any build tool like gulp or webpack.

So i have installed postcss and autoprefixer as follows:

```
npm install -g postcss autoprefixer
```

and then i'm trying to autoprefix a single file like so:

```
npx postcss --use autoprefixer --autoprefixer.flexbox --autoprefix.browser "> 0%" -o main.css test.css
```

It works for most of my code, but it does not include any prefix for flexbox in ie10.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You're targetting the latest browsers because you made a typo at `--autoprefix.browser`, it should be `autoprefixer.browser`

Answer (score 6):

The cli command that you are calling is for [postcss-cli-simple](https://github.com/pirxpilot/postcss-cli) not for *postcss* itself or *postcss-cli*

To use your command you have to install this packages

```
npm install postcss-cli-simple autoprefixer
```

And then is possible to use this command

```
./node_modules/.bin/postcss --use autoprefixer --autoprefixer.browsers "ie 10" -o main.css test.pcss
```

This command will convert this:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 calc(1vw - 1px);
}
```

Into this

```
body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 calc(1vw - 1px);
      flex: 1 0 calc(1vw - 1px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.browserslistrc` file

```
last 20 versions
```

[Link](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browserslist-)