# SCSS Autoprefixer in PhpStorm

Tags: sass, phpstorm, autoprefixer

I am trying to configure SASS/SCSS Autoprefixer in phpstorm and no solution here or anywhere on google is working for me, any help is appreciated...

I have tried many options including making a custom file watcher and using postcss-cli autoprefixer, but not able to get it right.

Answer (score 3):

As it's written in [this comment](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000149090-Autoprefixer?page=1#community_comment_115000188844), there is no built-in support for autoprefixer, and it can hardly be expected in near future. If you miss it, please vote for [WEB-37](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37).

You can install the [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#cli) (`npm install postcss-cli autoprefixer -g`) and set it up as a file watcher, for example

[image]

You can also try using [sass-prefix-mixins](https://github.com/ArtCodeStudio/sass-prefix-mixins) in your code

Comment: Hi @lena, thank you for your quick answer, but I have already used this method. The process runs successfully without any error, but there are not prefixes in CSS file, don't know why. Also, the CSS file is being generated by another watcher, SCSS watcher.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed the solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53807291

Comment: Hello, maybe I am late, but this don`t work at me too. What shoud I do, can u help me?