# Add autoprefixer to PhpStorm

Tags: sass, phpstorm, webstorm, autoprefixer

How to add `autoprefixer` using File Watcher in PhpStorm?

ATM I am using only SCSS preprocessor, but want to use `autoprefixer` too. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe start with what you've tried and some sample code you are looking at.

Comment: Okay, I`ve tried this:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415721/scss-autoprefixer-in-phpstorm

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000659610-Autoprefixer-in-file-watcher

Comment: And this dont work at me. I havent any errors, just dont compiles as need.

Comment: what doesn't work namely? What command did you try, what does your code look like? What is a result of running the same command in terminal?

Comment: Get commands from there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415721/scss-autoprefixer-in-phpstorm https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000659610-Autoprefixer-in-file-watcher And it is just dont work, there is no error, just dont

Comment: @ГлебЧерных Show how YOU tried it. 1) What command did you run to install the needed tool (show a screenshot showing that you have autoprefixer there). 2) How did YOU configured File Watcher. NOTE: there is an option to **always** show a console, regardless if it has an error or not. 3) On what file have you tried to run it. Maybe that file watcher is not applicable to that file (they way you set it up).