# How to configure PostCSS Autoprefixer as PhpStorm's File Watcher

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, postcss, autoprefixer, file-watcher

Thank you for your attention and your help! I really do appreciate it!

I use **PhpStorm** and node.js.

Can you please describe **as simple as possible** how to install globally **PostCSS** and **Autoprefixer** using terminal and configure PhpStorm's **file watcher**? I don't need to use gulp or webpack. I have a small project.

I tried different ways, but it doesn't work. PhpStorm generates a new .css file, but it doesn't contain prefixes.

I used
https://github.com/postcss/postcss and
https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

p.s. I tried to do it by myself for about several weeks...

Comment: did you try the suggestion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415721/scss-autoprefixer-in-phpstorm?

Comment: Hi @lena and thank you for quick response. I saw this method, but it didn't work to me. 
I guess I missed something before.

Comment: Can you post the values you have entered for the File Watcher fields?